# Let $a,x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, suppose $ax \equiv 1 \mod n$. Prove $a$ is coprime to $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, suppose $ax \equiv 1 \mod n$.  Prove $a$ is coprime to $n$.

How do I do this? I know so far that $ax=1+nk ~(k \in \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: You have pretty much proved it already.Check what you know so far and what you need for two numbers to be coprime.

Comment: I.e. $ax-nk=1$. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: To be coprime then $gcd(a,n)=1$ but I don't quite see this.

Comment: Prove it by contradiction. You know $ax=1+nk$.   

Assume for contr that $(a,n)=d>1$ (as usual, $(a,n)$ here denotes $\gcd(a,n)$). Then $d\mid a,n$ by the definition of $\gcd$, and $d\mid ax-nk=1\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1$, contradiction because $d>1$.

Comment: To understand some of the steps used, just remember the exact definition of divisibility: $(m\mid a)\iff (mk=a$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $ax+n(-k)=1$, this implies that an integer linear combination of $a$ and $n$ produces $1$. By definition, $\gcd(a,n)$ is the smallest positive linear combination of $a$ and $n$. Thus $\gcd(a,n)=1$, hence relatively prime.

Comment: I like your answer Anurag, however, $\gcd(a,b)$ is usually defined as the greatest integer such that it divides both $a$ and $b$ (that's where the name comes from). The definition you gave is usually given as a characterization.

Comment: @SolidSnake it depends on how one wants to introduce GCD. Actually the term "greatest" requires an ordering and proves to be a hurdle (that can be overcome) in generalizing the concept of GCD.

Comment: Exactly, but it's the natural definition, the one given from school and elemetary number theory courses. Once you are needed of generalization, that characterization appears (however, this characterization requires an order too! *smallest*, when you want to generalize what you need is the fact that $\gcd{a,b}$ is divided by any common divisor of $a$ and $b$). Never mind, this was just a (intended to be a) constructive comment! :)

Comment: @SolidSnake the ordering requirement in terms of "smallest" is a bit misleading because the idea is to consider GCD as a generator of the subgroup $a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover even at an elementary stage sometimes GCD is defined as the common divisor which is divisible by all other common divisors. This circumvents the need for ordering.

Comment: But it requires the ring to be a PID (of course, $\Bbb Z$ is a PID so there's no problem), that's why I've said: "If you're looking for generalization what you need is the fact that $\gcd(a,b)$ is divided by any common divisor of $a$ and $b$" and then we can define (in any ring, although it may not exist) $\gcd(a,b)$ as one of the common divisors of $a$ and $b$ such that it's divisible by any common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Proofwiki defines $(a,b)$ as $d$ such that $d\mid a,b$ and $k\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid d$, and gives provides $(a,b)$ being the smallest positive integer combination of $a,b$ as [Bezout's lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma) (thus something that is provable). It is very popular to see it as Bezout's lemma or identity, so you don't often see it as a definition.